# Where the refresh token and access token are stored while using JWT in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am trying to implement JWT using  **djangorestframework-simplejwt** for my Django rest application. I noticed that refresh token and access token are not stored in database. Then where are they stored?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the point of JWTs, they do not need server-side storage. All the information is baked into the token itself, which is *signed* with a secret only the server has (is supposed to have, if you do it properly without security vulnerability). The server reads the information in the JWT and confirms that it has been signed with the secret, something only it itself should have. If that succeeds, it trusts the information contained in the JWT. Hence it doesn't need to look up anything in any database.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I have got it. Token just travels with its expiry date in the payload. Thanks, I didn't consider it before. Could you please tell me how can I get payload data in django rest framework? As I also want to verify the user from the payload stored user_id.

Comment: djangorestframework-simplejwt is deeply integrated into Django, and the user will simply authenticate or not, and if they authenticate, they are accessible as the regular `.user` attribute of requests. The fact that the user was authenticated via JWT is mostly transparent. If you want to dive deeper into this process you'll need to be more detailed.